# Special dot masked input HTML-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masking

I'm trying to achieve a special masked input in HTML using jQuery and themask plugin from Igor Escobar (http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

I need write only numbers[0-9] and the following conversions:

**input:**

123456789

12345678

1234567

123456

**desidered output:**

123.456.789

12.345.678

1.234.567

123.456

Is possible achive this with that plugin?
Or exist another way to do it?
Thanks for reading :)

**EDIT:**

I did it using another plugin (Numeral.js):http://numeraljs.com/

This is my working code:

```
$("#myinput").blur(function() 
{
    this.value=numeral(this.value).format('0,0[.]00').replace(/\,/g, '.');
});
```

But I do not like to be validated at the end, ie (onblur), is there any way to do this on the fly? - That is, gradually validate (keypress).

Comment: $('.yourclass').mask('099.099.099.099'); ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that code result in this "123.456.78" if the input is "12345678", and i want "12.345.678"

Comment: Use `keyup` instead of `blur`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK something strange happens when I do that. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need a library for that. I kept jQuery but it's really used to select the input, so you definitely can ditch it quite easily.

```
$("#myinput").keyup(function(){
  // prevent every character except numbers
  if(!this.value.slice(-1).match(/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/) ){
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    return;
  }
  // remove the dots, split the string and reverse it
  var a = this.value.replace(/\./g, '').split('').reverse();

  // start from 3 and as long as there's a number 
  // add a dot every three digits.
  var pos = 3;
  while(a[pos] !== undefined){
    a.splice(pos,0,'.');
    pos = pos + 4;
  }  
  // reverse, join and reassign the value
  this.value = a.reverse().join('');
});
```

You can try it yourself <kbd>[here](http://jsbin.com/pokow/3/edit?js,output)</kbd> and see if it does the job. Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: while the above code works it has some shortcomings, such as:

- it does not work when copy/pasting
- it does not allow moving with arrow keys
- the cursor always goes to the end of the input, even when you are inserting a number in the middle.

As I needed it with full support for those cases I evolved it in a tiny script you can find on [Github](https://github.com/nobitagit/dotdot) along with a demo and test spec.

Comment: Nice, without plugins, only jQuery! clever!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myinput").on('keyup keydown blur', function() {
    this.value=numeral(this.value).format('0,0[.]00').replace(/\,/g, '.');
}
```

Comment: Something strange happens when I do that. Try it. And, please add ");" to the final of your code.